# \theoremindent adds space to left side when used with RTL languages

Tags: indentation, theorems, polyglossia, ntheorem, right-to-left

Trying to use `ntheorem`'s `\theoremindent` seems to indent the left side rather than the right side when used with `polyglossia` and right-to-left languages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremindent2cm
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{theorem}{משפט}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=hebrew, numerals=arabic]{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{David CLM}

\begin{document}
א א א א א א א א א א א א א א א א א א א א א א א א א א א א א א א א א א א א א א
\begin{theorem}
ב ב ב ב ב ב ב ב ב ב ב ב ב ב ב ב ב ב ב ב ב ב ב ב ב ב ב ב ב ב ב
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this fixable?

Also it seems the numbering and separators are displayed wrong.

Comment: Note that the positioning of the colon (:) is also wrong: To the right, rather than the left, of the number. I guess `ntheorem` is very RTL-oriented in general...

Comment: Have split-off the separator question to [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37997/5640).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offending lines in `ntheorem-hyper.sty` (or `ntheorem.sty`, depending on your distribution) seem to be:

```
\newdimen\theoremindent
\global\theoremindent0cm
\newdimen\theorem@indent
%...
\advance\@totalleftmargin \theorem@indent
\parshape \@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth
```

So, unsurprisingly, `ntheorem` assumes margins are on the left. Here's a suggested micro-patch, partially due to @egreg:

```
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{polyglossia}{
\patchcmd{\@thm}
  {\advance\@totalleftmargin\theorem@indent}
  {\if@RTL\else\advance\@totalleftmargin\theorem@indent\fi}
  {}{}
}
\makeatother
```

This should be adaptable into a patch for `ntheorem-hyper.sty` itself.

Comment: I could not post this as a comment so I had to post it as an answer. A modified version of Eyal/Egreg's patch is added to version 11.152 of bidi package which should be on CTAN soon.

Comment: user13617 Have a look at the [faq] to know why you cannot comment yet. That's not a reason to use features with a different purpose instead.