# RTL theorems with ntheorem and xetex have separator in wrong place

Tags: theorems, polyglossia, ntheorem, right-to-left

(This is a split-off from [another RTL ntheorem issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37920/5640).)

When you have a theorem in RTL language text (e.g. Hebrew), using XeTeX+`polyglossia`(+`bidi`)+`ntheorem`, the theorem separator comes out before, rather than after, the theorem number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{theorem}{משפט}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=arabic]{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{David} % You may need David CLM

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
משפט מחוזי מאוד.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Same thing happens for a full-stop separator. Using MikTeX 2.9. Result of `\listfiles`:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
ntheorem.sty    2011/02/16 1.31
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
polyglossia.sty    2010/07/27 v1.2.0a Babel replacement for XeLaTeX
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
makecmds.sty    2009/09/03 v1.0a extra command making commands
fontspec.sty    2011/02/26 v2.1f Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX
   expl3.sty    2011/06/19 v2478 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper
 l3names.sty    2011/06/19 v2478 L3 Experimental namespace for primitives
l3bootstrap.sty    2011/06/19 v2478 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
    calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
l3basics.sty    2011/07/04 v2493 L3 Experimental basic definitions
 l3expan.sty    2011/06/20 v2480 L3 Experimental argument expansion
    l3tl.sty    2011/07/09 v2498 L3 Experimental token lists
   l3seq.sty    2011/06/19 v2478 L3 Experimental sequences and stacks
   l3int.sty    2011/06/19 v2478 L3 Experimental integers
 l3quark.sty    2011/06/19 v2478 L3 Experimental quarks
   l3prg.sty    2011/07/06 v2495 L3 Experimental control structures
 l3clist.sty    2011/07/09 v2498 L3 Experimental comma separated lists
 l3token.sty    2011/07/02 v2491 L3 Experimental token manipulation
  l3prop.sty    2011/06/19 v2478 L3 Experimental property lists
   l3msg.sty    2011/06/19 v2478 L3 Experimental messages
    l3io.sty    2011/06/19 v2478 L3 Experimental input-output operations
  l3file.sty    2011/06/19 v2478 L3 Experimental file operations
  l3skip.sty    2011/06/19 v2478 L3 Experimental dimensions and skips
   l3box.sty    2011/06/19 v2478 L3 Experimental boxes
l3keyval.sty    2011/06/19 v2478 L3 Experimental key-value parsing
  l3keys.sty    2011/06/19 v2478 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces
    l3fp.sty    2011/06/19 v2478 L3 Experimental floating-point operations
l3luatex.sty    2011/06/19 v2478 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
  l3toks.sty    2011/06/19 v2478 L3 Experimental token registers
  xparse.sty    2011/07/02 v2492 L3 Experimental document command parser
 xkeyval.sty    2008/08/13 v2.6a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2008/08/13 v2.6a key=value parser (HA)
fontspec-patches.sty    2011/02/26 v2.1f Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX/Lu
aLaTeX
fixltx2e.sty    2006/09/13 v1.1m fixes to LaTeX
 fontenc.sty
  eu1enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
  eu1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
xunicode.sty    2010/11/06 v0.96 provides access to latin accents and many othe
r characters in Unicode lower plane
fontspec.cfg
gloss-hebrew.ldf    polyglossia: module for hebrew
    bidi.sty    2011/03/21 v1.1.6 <commit 145> Bidirectional typesetting in pla
in TeX and LaTeX
   iftex.sty    2010/07/25 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX,
 and LuaTeX
loadingorder-bidi.def    2010/07/25 v0.5 making sure that bidi is the last pack
age loaded
xetex-bidi.def    2010/08/01 v0.8 bidi adaptations for XeTeX engine
footnote-xetex-bidi.def    2010/07/25 v0.5 bidi footnote macros for XeTeX engin
e
article-xetex-bidi.def    2010/07/25 v0.4 bidi adaptations for standard article
 class for XeTeX engine
hebrewcal.sty    2008/07/01 v2.4 Hebrew calendar for polyglossia (adapted from 
hebcal.sty in Babel)
cal-util.def
babel-hebrewalph.def    2010/03/02 Babel definitions for Hebrew numerals
 Adapted from hebrew.ldf (2005/03/30 v2.3h)
```

Comment: Doesn't happen to me; your theorem appears to be in upshape, while the default is italics. Have you got other customizations?

Comment: Using just this code with MikTeX 2.9

Comment: I get the colon to the left of the number. May you add the result of `\listfiles`?

Comment: You have many outdated files; `polyglossia`, `bidi` and `fontspec` should be updated.

Comment: I have the latest of all the above (texlive-2011) and I'm seeing the same thing as Eyal.

Comment: @egreg: A solution saying "update to version so-and-so of packages so-and-so" is perfectly acceptable... although maybe this isn't the problem, like Daniel suggests.

Comment: @egreg: The upshape is due to David not having an italic version for some reason. Although I have Culmus installed and everything.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite curious, but it seems font dependent. With the "New Peninim MT" font I get the colon in the right place, with "David CLM" not.

However, the following seems to work:

```
\theoremseparator{\textup{:}}
```

An update to the most recent versions of `polyglossia`, `bidi` and `fontspec` is recommendable nonetheless.

Comment: Confirmed the `\textup` workaround with David on MikTeX 2.9. A weird bug indeed.