# Tables are not numbered using Polyglossia in Hebrew

Tags: floats, xetex, numbering, polyglossia, hebrew

I have a problem using Polyglossia in Hebrew:
While defining main language as Hebrew, my tables are not numbered in the caption(It appraes as just "Table" (טבלה) instead of "Table 1" (or "טבלה 1").
If I change the main language back to English - the table is captioned as "Table 1" without problems.

Any suggestions how can I bring back the numbers to the caption of the tables?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}


\setmainfont{David}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Arial}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
  \hline
    & speed & dist \\ 
  \hline
  1 &  4.00 &  2.00 \\ 
  2 &  4.00 & 10.00 \\ 
  3 &  7.00 &  4.00 \\ 
  4 &  7.00 & 22.00 \\ 
  5 &  8.00 & 16.00 \\ 
  6 &  9.00 & 10.00 \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{סתם טבלה}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If I use David CLM as main font I get numbers.

Comment: @egreg, Thanks! Now I get an error saying
The current roman font does not contain the Hebrew script!
Please define \hebrewfont with \newfontfamily.
When I add David CLM as hebrewfont, it compiles as gibberish...

Comment: OK... Making a progress here. 
If I use another font (e.g Ezra SIL or Miriam CLM) in the New font famile (\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Miriam CLM})  the table does get numbered, BUT the colon appears right to the "1" i.e "1:", instead of ":1" as should appear in RTL language. Suggestions?

Comment: @egreg, It seems you have solved this issue here  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37997/rtl-theorems-with-ntheorem-and-xetex-have-separator-in-wrong-place . How can I get to the table seperator ?

Comment: I don't know what to say: with David CLM as main font I don't need to declare a `\hebrewfont` family and I get "הלבט םתס :1 הלבט", but reversed. That is, the colon is to the left of `1`.

Comment: @Shmulik: I get the same error you are getting: "...does not contain the Hebrew script...". And I can't ever compile with David CLM anyway, I don't even get gibberish... Anyway, I think you should: (1) Edit your question with the change and (2) ask another question about the table separator, and link to my question about the theorem separator.

Comment: This is a MiKTeX bug. MiKTeX has included a buggy XeTeX binary for several years. I am afraid, the solution is that you need to uninstall MiKTeX and install TeXLive instead. See exactly the same bug: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52575/number-not-displayed-in-parentheses

Comment: @Vafa, Thanks. I will do it.
Eyal - Unfortunately the issue is solved, so I don't see a real point of posting new question.Don't you think so?

Comment: @Shmulik: If you mean the separator issue, there's a workaround, not a solution. But posting a comment there linking back here is also relevant. This question is a bit messy with our discussion going in different directions which may be a bit confusing for new visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem here using MAC OSX 10.7.4 and TeXLive 2012:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}


\setmainfont{Adobe Hebrew}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Arial}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
  \hline
 & speed & dist \\ 
  \hline
1 & 4.00 & 2.00 \\ 
  2 & 4.00 & 10.00 \\ 
  3 & 7.00 & 4.00 \\ 
  4 & 7.00 & 22.00 \\ 
  5 & 8.00 & 16.00 \\ 
  6 & 9.00 & 10.00 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{סתם טבלה}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

here is the output I get which is perfectly fine:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

@Ulrike: This should be your minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\TeXXeTstate=1
\font\body="Adobe Hebrew:script=hebrew" at 12pt % replace "Adobe Hebew" with some other Hebrew font
\begin{document}
\hbox{\beginR\body
טבלה
1:
סתם טבלה
\endR}
\end{document}
```

Using TeXLive 2012 on Mac OS X 10.7.4, this is what I get which is the expected behaviour:

[image]

If you get anything else, then that is the bug of MiKTeX. Indeed, MiKTeX has included a buggy version of XeTeX binary for several years. For details, see [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52575/number-not-displayed-in-parentheses).

Comment: Vafa, thanks. I put my money that it has something to do with MikTeX's Xelatex or Windows fonts, as You and @egreg compiled it perfectly. The fact that the problem is for table caption is irrelevant, as it also appears in Figures and Theorems captions. I'd be glad to hear from Win-PC Polyglossia RTL user some hints...

Comment: Perhaps a MiKTeX bug like this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52575/number-not-displayed-in-parentheses

Comment: @Vafa: Well you complicated things a bit by introducing the `script=hebrew`. I don't have the adobe font but made some tests with Erza SIL: *Without* the script-option ` 123: ` is typed left-to-right and so give `123:`. *With* the `script=..` ` 123: ` is handled like the mix `abמאוד` in my example: glyphs are lost and the result is `:12`. The `:1` from your example disappears completly. So there is a difference between Miktex (on Windows) and TeXLive (on MaC OS). But if this means that one of both is buggy (and which one) I don't dare to say.

Comment: @Ulrike: That is the main point. without script option, my output is exactly the same as yours. But with script option, it makes sense that we both get the expected behaviour, if I get the expected behaviour but you do not, would not that be the bug of MiKTeX? can you recall this? (It is actually the same bug which has not been fixed yet, the bug did not exist in earlier versions of MiKTeX): http://tug.org/mailman/htdig/xetex/2011-July/020885.html

Comment: @Vafa: But I don't know what is the "expected" behaviour. You are mixing *in one word* "western" glyphs (the numbers 123), which should be printed from left to right in the order of the input with "hebrew glyphs" which should be printed in reversed order. It sounds easy to claim that "123:" should be printed as ":123". But what is with "12:30:80"? Btw: I don't think that miktex does something special in its xetex implementation. By guess is that some library is different for windows than for mac os.

Comment: @Ulrike: The expected behaviour is that no glyph should be lost when `script=hebrew` is used (provided the font we are using has glyphs 123, etc). Further XeTeX uses ICU layout which itself uses some unibidi algorithm. `:` is a weak character so `123:` should be printed (when `script=hebrew` is used) `:123` and `12:30:80` should  should be printed as `12:30:80`. This is MiKTeX only bug. I tried the same thing on Windows with both TeXLive 2011 and TeXLive 2012 and the result is exactly identical to that of Mac OS X 10.7.4.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, Thanks for the effort and the example. I think Vafa has a point here about the glyph's direction.

Comment: @Shmulik: I don't doubt that Vafa has a point. But I don't want to make a miktex bug report without clear informations. Vage bug reports are  useless as they are simply closed. In this case the OS, the fonts, the editor used to save a tex-file could all be important (see e.g. this for differences between Mac and Windows: http://tug.org/mailman/htdig/xetex/2009-May/013071.html). If I find some time I will test with TeXLive.

Comment: @Ulrike: What information do you need? OS=Windows 7 ultimate, TeX distribution=MiKTeX 2.9, TeX editor=TeXWorks or any other editor supporting unicode, Font= Adobe Hebrew, or Ezra SIL or any other hebrew font, Minimal working example= provided in my updated answer.

Comment: @Vafa: I made a bug report: https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3532167&group_id=10783&atid=110783. Let's see what christian says.

Comment: Hi. I approve it to work perfectly under TexLive and using Vafa's suggestion : \newfontfamily\hebrewfont{David CLM:script=hebrew}.
Thanks everybody for the help!

Comment: @Shmulik: If  you are using Polyglossia, should either use `\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}` or simply `\setmainfont{David CLM}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks heaps for your kindness to do the bug report. I actually reported this bug 2 years ago to Christian personally but let's hope that it gets fixed this time. MiKTeX is a nice TeX distribution.

Comment: @Vafa Christian has reacted to my bug report: with version 0.9998 (coming soon) my example (the on in the bug report) will give the same output as the xetex in texlive 2012. Regarding bug reports in miktex: You should be really thorough when making a report. The more informations the better. If Christian can reproduce the problem from the report and the report contains some proof that it is a miktex problem (and not due to a package or an external binary) then the bug normally gets fixed fast. If not he will close the report without remorse due to insufficient informations.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks again for this. Christian says in your bug report that version of 0.9998 of XeTeX fixes this (meaning that the bug existed in XeTeX and now it is fixed) but that is not correct. Version  0.9997.5 of XeTeX from TeXLive 2011 had also no problem (producing the same output as version 0.9998 of XeTeX). Hence it appears to me that something was wrong with MiKTeX XeTeX binary.

Comment: Christian that the bug is fixed in "MiKTeX-XeTeX 0.9998". This doesn't say anyhing about the source of the bug. If you look at the git repository of XeTeX you can see that between 2010 (when Jonathan stopped more or less the XeTeX support) and 2012 there was some differences between the code of TeXLive-XeTeX and the "official" XeTeX code.

Comment: @Vafa, Using TeXLive, it seems to work perfectly only when I define \newfontfamily\hebrewfont{David CLM:script=hebrew}. Otherwise using \setmainfont{David CLM} it won't compile saying "The current roman font does not contain the Hebrew script!
Please define \hebrewfont with \newfontfamily". Using \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM} would just compile with the colon direction problem as described before...

Comment: @Shmulik: It is indeed because the font does not contain Hebrew script (it is a font bug). Use another font, say "Times New Roman" and compare the outputs with using `Script=Hebrew` option and without it. (Also see my last comment on Eyal's answer).

Comment: @vafa, Right You are. Works perfect with \setmainfont{David}.

Answer (score 1):

@Eyal, @Vafa:

Regarding the problem with the separator. I don't know if it is due to a bug in miktex as I don't know what is the indented or wanted behaviour (how e.g. should the number 123 be printed in hebrew? As 123 or 321?). But if it is bug then the first step is to simplify the problem. Examples which relies on fontspec, polyglossia, bidi and unknown fonts will not be useful in a bug report.

I boiled down the problem to the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\font\test="Arial Unicode MS"
\font\test="Ezra SIL"
\TeXXeTstate=1

 \chardef\popDirection"202C
 \chardef\forceLtoR"202D
 \chardef\forceRtoL"202E
\begin{document}
%non-unicode font
\beginR
abc 123:
\endR

%unicode-font
\test
abc 123:  456\mbox{}:  מאוד abמאוד :מאוד

\beginR
abc 123:  456\mbox{}:  מאוד abמאוד :מאוד
\endR

\beginR
\forceRtoL 123:  
\forceRtoL abמאוד
\endR

\end{document}
```

This give this result for me with miktex 2.9 (the result with arial unicode is similar):

[image]

It is obvious that as soon as unicode-fonts are used the direction *inside* "words" depends on the unicode plane of the chars involved: Words with numbers or chars like "abc" together with punctuation chars like colons or dots are printed left-to-right even in a RTL context (and the other way round). Words which mix chars from left-to-right and right-to-left-planes can swallow preceding chars due to the direction change. What do you get on TeXLive?

Comment: Numbers mustn't be reversed.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows XP.

Here's what I get with Ulrike's MWE (with FrankRuehl as the font):

[image: screenshot]

and this is without the `script=hebrew` (as per Vafa's comment):

[image: screenshot]

so, no number glyph and no colon glpyh in the first image, and they appear again in the second image. Also, there's the [separator bug Shmulik linked to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37997/5640). Finally, note the spacing differences - the glyphs are not replaced with whitespace of the same width - but there is some extra space in the first example.

With Shmulik's code + slight change of the font command I get some strange behavior:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}

%\setmainfont{David}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{David}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Arial}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
  \hline
    & speed & dist \\
  \hline
  1 &  4.00 &  2.00 \\
  2 &  4.00 & 10.00 \\
  3 &  7.00 &  4.00 \\
  4 &  7.00 & 22.00 \\
  5 &  8.00 & 16.00 \\
  6 &  9.00 & 10.00 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{סתם טבלה}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

The non-Hebrew characters do seem to be David, but the Hebrew is in some other font.

Comment: How do you want that to be correct when there is no `Script=Hebrew` option in your `\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{David}`?

Comment: Oh, well that gives you: `fontspec warning: "script-not-exist"
Font 'David' does not contain script 'Hebrew'.` And with some other fonts it works without the [Script=Hebrew].

Comment: That is the main point. The font should contain Hebrew script, if it does not contain Hebrew script and you do not use it, things do not work properly. As an example try my minimal example, replace Adobe Hebrew with Ezra SIL, run xelatex on it and see the output, second time, remove script=hebrew: `font\body="Ezra SIL" at 12pt`. Now compare the outputs. Can you see what Hebrew script effects has?

Comment: @VafaKhalighi: done. Also, David certainly does contain Hebrew script, I use it all the time in Word Processing. Perhaps that's misreported somehow, or misunderstood by MikTeX.

Comment: Containing Hebrew glyphs is quite different to containing Hebrew Script (this is like a script tag that the font should have). Even if a font does not contain Hebrew script but contains Hebrew glyphs, you are still able to typeset Hebrew with it but not properly. I do not think, this is misreported or misunderstood. For more details, please see http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otfntdev/hebrewot/appen.aspx

Comment: @VafaKhalighi: Well, David is a very widely-used font. I'm assuming this is a problem with several/multiple other relatively popular fonts. It might be argued that itsa shortcoming should be accounted for somehow (e.g. by allowing an override when the script is missing but the glyphs are there?) Anyway, this is pretty off-topic for the bug, so never mind right now.